# Transition from Modal View to Next VC in a TabBar and NavBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, transition

I'm using Swift 2 and xcode 7.1.1.

My app is a tabbar + navigationbar based application.

**What I'd like to do:**
From my first viewcontroller (`CollectionVC`) I have a collectionview of images(tabbar at bottom and navbar at top). When you select an image, I transition programmatically to a modalviewcontroller (`ImageZoomVC`) that allows them to zoom on the image (no tabbar or navbar). From the `ImageZoomVC` I want to transition programmatically to the `UserProfileVC`. The `UserProfileVC` should have the tabbar and navbar like the first view. The navbars back button should also take us back to the `ImageZoomVC`.

This workflow is similar to facebook. When you select an image, you go to a black screen with just that image and some more info. You can click on anyone tagged in the image and it will push their profile onscreen with the tabbar and navbar back in place.

**The Problem:**
Once in the `ImageZoomVC`, I can't transition to the `UserProfileVC` without losing the tabbar and navbar. I've been able to add a navbar programmatically but there is no back button, and setting a back button hasn't worked. Also, there is no tabbar.

**Code:**
From my `CollectionVC`, I transition to the `ImageZoomVC` from my collectioncell like this:

```
@IBAction func PhotoButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let imageZoom = ImageZoomVC()
        imageZoom.showFrom(self.parentView!)
}
```

Here is the `showFrom` function that presents the `ImageZoomVC` modally. This code is inside the ImageZoomVC:

```
    public func showFrom(viewController: UIViewController) {

    //Some stuff here, edited for length

            viewController.presentViewController(self, animated: false) {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(ImageZoomVC.TransitionAnimationDuration,
                    delay: 0,
                    options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, .CurveEaseInOut],
                    animations: {
                        [weak self] in
                        self?.collectionView.alpha = 1
                        self?.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    },
                    completion: {
                        [weak self] finished in
                        self?.view.userInteractionEnabled = finished
                    }
                )
            }
    }
```

This is the code I'm attempting to use to transition to the UserProfileVC with navbar and tabbar. This doesn't work. It will present the VC, but there is no tabbar or back button.

```
    func userSelected (sender: UIButton) {
         let vc = self.presentingViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("User Profile") as! UserProfileVC
         let newNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
         newNav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor().specialPurple()
         newNav.navigationBar.translucent = false
         self.presentViewController(newNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**A couple notes:** The `ImageZoomVC` doesn't exist in storyboard. It is called and instantiated programmatically.

The `ImageZoomVC` is based off Agrume from Github found here:
https://github.com/JanGorman/Agrume

I'd like to push the `UserProfileVC` like facebook does. This current code presents it from the bottom. The code pushViewController is not recognized here in xCode.

Let me know what you think. All thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Your ImageViewVC could call a mehod of its calling view controller which dismisses ImageViewVC and then peforms a regular segue or pushes the next view controller (UserProfileVC) programmatically.

Comment: Yeah. That is a good point. However, the UX isn't what I'm going for... where one view dismisses, presents the previous view and then pushes to the third view all in front of the user. Also, the back button in the 'UserProfileVC' would then return to the 'CollectionVC' and not the 'ImageZoomVC'. Would there be a way to hide/mask the transition back to the 'CollectionVC' and only show the push transition to the 'UserProfileVC'? I might be able to live with the back button not returning to the 'ImageZoomVC'.